# Django: posting information to multiple models with one html form

Tags: django, post, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I'm building my first solo django project right now so I'm learning a lot. I've run into a problem that I can't think how to fix. For a fantasy football app project, I've represented each type of player position with their own model. Like this...

```
class Quarterback(models.Model):  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

     
class Runningback(models.Model):  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Widereceiver(models.Model):  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Tightend(models.Model):  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20) 

            
class Kicker(models.Model):  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

I have a "choose player" page that uses javascript to fill in model forms that I've made for each player model. This is my forms.py

```
class Quarterbackform(forms.ModelForm):  
    class Meta:  
        model = Quarterback 
        fields = "__all__" 
        widgets = {
        'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':'QB_name'})
        }

class Runningbackform(forms.ModelForm):  
    class Meta:  
        model = Runningback  
        fields = "__all__"  
        widgets = {
        'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':'RB_name'})
        }

class Widereceiverform(forms.ModelForm):  
    class Meta:  
        model = Widereceiver  
        fields = "__all__"
        widgets = {
        'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':'WR_name'})
        }  

class Tightendform(forms.ModelForm):  
    class Meta:  
        model = Tightend 
        fields = "__all__"
        widgets = {
        'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':'TE_name'})
        }  

class Kickerform(forms.ModelForm):  
    class Meta:  
        model = Kicker  
        fields = "__all__"
        widgets = {
        'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':'K_name'})
        }
```

My views.py has this function to save player selections to their respective model.

```
def emp(request):  
   

    url = 'hidden'
 
    r = requests.get(url.format()).json()
    
    player_data = []
    #print(r)
    for i in r:
        player_info = {
            'player_id' : i['PlayerID'],
            'player_name' : i['Name'],
            'team' : i['Team'],
            'position': i['Position'],
            'points': i['FantasyPoints']
        }

        player_data.append(player_info)
    #print(player_data)


    if request.method == "POST":  
        QBform = Quarterbackform(request.POST)  
        if QBform.is_valid():  
            try:  
                QBform.save()  
                return redirect('show')  
            except:  
                pass  
    else:  
        QBform = Quarterbackform() 
    

    # New Player/Form

    if request.method == "POST":  
        RBform = Runningbackform(request.POST)  
        if RBform.is_valid():  
            try:  
                RBform.save()  
                return redirect('show')  
            except:  
                pass  
    else:  
        RBform = Runningbackform() 

     # New Player/Form

    if request.method == "POST":  
        WRform = Widereceiverform(request.POST)  
        if WRform.is_valid():  
            try:  
                WRform.save()  
                return redirect('show')  
            except:  
                pass  
    else:  
        WRform = Widereceiverform() 

     # New Player/Form

    if request.method == "POST":  
        TEform = Tightendform(request.POST)  
        if TEform.is_valid():  
            try:  
                form.save()  
                return redirect('show')  
            except:  
                pass  
    else:  
        TEform = Tightendform() 

     # New Player/Form

    if request.method == "POST":
        Kform = Kickerform(request.POST)  
        if Kform.is_valid():  
            try:  
                Kform.save()  
                return redirect('show')  
            except:  
                pass  
    else:  
        Kform = Kickerform() 

   

    
    context = {'player_data': player_data,
               'QBform': QBform,
               'RBform': RBform,
               'WRform': WRform,
               'TEform': TEform,
               'Kform': Kform
    }
     
    return render(request,'game/form.html', context)
```

I'm also using this function to show/render the selected players.

```
def show(request): 

    user = request.user

    if user.is_authenticated: 

        try:
            QB = Quarterback.objects.values_list('name', flat="True")[0]
        except IndexError:
            QB = 'empty'

        try:
            RB = Runningback.objects.values_list('name', flat="True")[0]
        except IndexError:
            RB = 'empty'

        try:     
            WR = Widereceiver.objects.values_list('name', flat="True")[0]
        except IndexError:
            WR = 'empty'

        try:
            TE = Tightend.objects.values_list('name', flat="True")[0]
        except IndexError:
            TE = 'empty' 

        try:    
            K = Kicker.objects.values_list('name', flat="True")[0]
        except IndexError:
            K = 'empty' 



        context = {
            'QB': QB[0:],
            'RB': RB[0:],
            'WR': WR[0:],
            'TE': TE[0:],
            'K': K[0:]
        }


        return render(request,"game/show.html", context)
```

This is the html page for selecting players. As you can see, each form input area gets populated by a javascript onclick function.

```
{% extends "game/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block body %}

<form method="POST" class="post-form" action="/game/emp">  
    {% csrf_token %}  
<div class="container">  
<br>  
<div class="form-group row">  
<label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label"></label>  
<div class="col-sm-4">  
<h3>Enter Details</h3>  
</div>  
</div>  
<div class="form-group row">  
<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Quarterback:</label>  
<div class="col-sm-4">  
  {{ QBform }}  
</div>  
</div>  
<div class="form-group row">  
<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Running Back:</label>  
<div class="col-sm-4">  
  {{ RBform }}  
</div>  
</div>  
<div class="form-group row">  
<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Wide Receiver:</label>  
<div class="col-sm-4">  
  {{ WRform }}  
</div>  
</div>  
<div class="form-group row">  
<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Tight End:</label>  
<div class="col-sm-4">  
  {{ TEform }}  
</div>  
</div>  
<div class="form-group row">  
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Kicker:</label>  
    <div class="col-sm-4">  
      {{ Kform }}  
    </div>  
    </div> 
<div class="form-group row">  
<label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label"></label>  
<div class="col-sm-4">  
<button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>  
</div>  
</div>  
</div>  
</form> 
<br>
<br>
<br>
<script>

    function myFunction(txt) {
        var myTxt = txt;
       
        
        if (txt.includes('QB')) {
            document.getElementById("QB_name").value = myTxt;
        }

        else if (txt.includes('RB')) {
            document.getElementById("RB_name").value = myTxt;
        }

        else if (txt.includes('WR')) {
            document.getElementById("WR_name").value = myTxt;
        }

        else if (txt.includes('TE')) {
            document.getElementById("TE_name").value = myTxt;
        }

        else if (txt.includes('K')) {
            document.getElementById("K_name").value = myTxt;
        }
        
    }
    
</script>


{% for player_data in player_data %}
<li><p>Player ID: {{ player_data.player_id }}: {{ player_data.player_name }}, {{ player_data.team }}, {{ player_data.position }}, {{ player_data.points }}</p></li> <button  onclick="myFunction('{{ player_data.player_name }} {{ player_data.position }} {{ player_data.points }}')">Add</button>
{% endfor %} 

{% endblock %}
```

The problem I'm having is that only one object is actually being saved. In this case, it's only saving the kicker object and is saving it in the Quarterback model for some strange reason. I suspect this is because the form and its submit button can only send a post request to one form only. If that is the case, is it possible to have all 5 objects saved with just one click/submit? So far, this is the only theory I have as to why only one object is saving correctly. I'd appreciate any advice. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to create multiple `ModelForm`. You can create a regular [`Form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django), keep the fields for all the models in it.

Example:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    quarterback_name = forms.CharField(label='Quarterback', max_length=100)
    runningback_name = forms.CharField(label='Runningback', max_length=100)
    # Add other fields ...

    def save(self):
        # Here you can update the corresponding models
        quarterback_name = self.cleaned_data.get('quarterback_name')
        Quarterback.objects.create(name=quarterback_name)

        # ... same for other models ...
```

---

**Note:** Instead of creating separate models for each type of player, you can create a single model called `Player` and then set the role of each player:

```python
class Player(models.Model):
    PLAYER_ROLE_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'Quarterback'),
        (2, 'Runningback'),
        (3, 'Tightend'),
        # and so on
    )
    role = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=PLAYER_ROLE_CHOICES)
```

Please read more about [`choices` in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#choices).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Originally, I did start with one model for an entire team roster of players/positions and a form to go with it but I couldn't get it to render correctly. I didn't have anything like the "def save" function in my model though. I'm guessing it takes the place of a view function for saving updating the corresponding models?

Comment: @user14593966 Yes, the `save` method helps to keep saving/editing logic in the form instead of in the view.